# O simbolo + no nome de um site pode afetar as pesquisas?

Tags: seo

Boa noite, tenho um site que tem no nome o simbolo +, isto pode afetar as pesquisas no Google, sera melhor colocar no nome do site ...Mais?

Comment: Tem + no nome ou usa URLs com + ?

Comment: Algumas destas respostas lhe atenderam?

Comment: Sim, obrigado pela ajuda a todos

Answer (score 1):

Proibido não é porem `Crawlers` e `Spiders` podem não interpretar o simbolo com o mesmo objetivo que você na hora que o colocou, para eles faz mais sentido o `-` ser um separador de palavras, um `+` ser um espaço ou o caracter de soma.

Fontes:

- [Avoid plus symbol from URL](http://www.orchidbox.com/post.php?title=Google_Recommends_Avoidance_of_the_plus_sign_in_URLs)
- [Google Drops Plus Sign from Search Operators](http://www.seochat.com/c/a/google-optimization-help/google-drops-plus-sign-from-search-operators/)
- [URLs: Should I use hyphens, underscores or plus symbols?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/374/urls-should-i-use-hyphens-underscores-or-plus-symbols)

Answer (score 0):

**Não use muitos caracteres especiais no título de sua página**. Os motores de pesquisa tendem a ignorar caracteres especiais. Por exemplo, [o Google ignora pontuações e outros símbolos especiais](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433?hl=en). Os separadores mais utilizados é o `|` e o `-`.

> Padaria do Zé - Início
>
> Padaria do Zé - Salgados
>
> Padaria do Zé - Doces

A chave é montar um título com base no contexto do seu site: `Seu Site | Assunto`. A primeira ação dos usuários é clicar na informação desejada, que será disponibilizada pelo seu site. Logo associar esse comportamento ao "brand" de sua empresa é uma boa oportunidade para manter uma impressão e retorno ao seu site.

Respondendo sua pergunta, o uso de um `+` no seu título não vai afetar seus resultados de pesquisa.

**Fontes:**

[15 Title Tag Optimization Guidelines For Usability and SEO](http://usabilitygeek.com/15-title-tag-optimization-guidelines-for-usability-and-seo/)

[Google Search Help](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433?hl=en)

[SEO na title tag](http://www.agenciamestre.com/seo/seo-na-title-tag/)

Comment: Obrigado pela sua Resposta

Answer (score 0):

Uma opção também seria você utilizar o nome "mais" e trabalhar com HTML Meta Elements no Head do seu código fonte.
Segue um exemplo do w3schools

```
<meta name="keywords" content="HTML, CSS, XML, XHTML, JavaScript">
```

Comment: meta-keywords não são mais considerado uma prática para o uso e a resposta me parece um pouco fora do contexto da duvida do autor, poderia ser mais claro?